# BeautifulSoup elements output to list

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have an output using BeautifulSoup.

1. I need to convert the output from *'type' 'bs4.element.Tag'* to a list and export the list into a DataFrame column, named  *COLUMN_A*
2. I want my output to stop at the 14th element *(the last three `h2` are useless)*

My code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.planetware.com/tourist-attractions-/oslo-n-osl-oslo.htm'
url_get = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(url_get.content, 'html.parser')
attraction_place=soup.find_all('h2', class_="sitename")    

for attraction in attraction_place:
    print(attraction.text)
    type(attraction)
```

Output:

```
1  Vigeland Sculpture Park
2  Akershus Fortress
3  Viking Ship Museum
4  The National Museum
5  Munch Museum
6  Royal Palace
7  The Museum of Cultural History
8  Fram Museum
9  Holmenkollen Ski Jump and Museum
10  Oslo Cathedral
11  City Hall (Rådhuset)
12  Aker Brygge
13  Natural History Museum & Botanical Gardens
14  Oslo Opera House and Annual Music Festivals
Where to Stay in Oslo for Sightseeing
Tips and Tours: How to Make the Most of Your Visit to Oslo
More Related Articles on PlanetWare.com
```

I expect a list like:

```
attraction=[Vigeland Sculpture Park, Akershus Fortress, ......]
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nice easy way is to take the `alt` attribute of the photos. This gets clean text output and only 14 without any need for slicing/indexing.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.planetware.com/tourist-attractions-/oslo-n-osl-oslo.htm')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
attractions = [item['alt'] for item in soup.select('.photo [alt]')]
print(attractions)
```

Comment: Excellent! You made my day QHarr.

Answer (score 1):

```py
new = []
count = 1
for attraction in attraction_place:
    while count < 15:
        text = attraction.text
        new.append(text)
        count += 1
```

Comment: It is only producing 1 element of 14

Answer (score 1):

You can use slice.

```
for attraction in attraction_place[:14]:
    print(attraction.text)
    type(attraction)
```